# Entity Framework: adding two model with relation same time to my database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to add some data to my database using Entity Framework code-first approach.

This is my code:

```
Member member = new Member
                {
                     ...
                     Cards = new List<Card>() {new Card {  Number = model.CartBankNumber, RegisterTime = DateTime.Now, Status = CardStatus.Verifying }  },
                };
db.Member.Add(member);
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This is my `Member` model class:

```
public class Member
{
    ...
    public Member()
    {
        Cards = new List<Card>();
    }

    [Display(Name = "Cards", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    public virtual ICollection<Card> Cards{ get; set; }
}
```

And `Card` model class:

```
public class Card
{
    ...
    [Display(Name = "Id", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Member")]
    public string MemberId { get; set; }

    public virtual Member Member { get; set;}
}
```

Why is `MemberId` null?

[image: Card Table]

Comment: Could you please show us the primary key property of Member?

Comment: `[Key, ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]`. Sorry i forgot that. Member have a one to one relation to User model. i set Id of Membr when i Create a new Member `Id = user.Id,`